# Custom module controller getView()->renderTemplate() path not working

Tags: craft3, php, yii

Module loads and controller actions work. Craft 3.3.7.

I'm trying to find out what is the path to use to render the view.

From the Doc:

```
return $this->renderTemplate('plugin-handle/path/to/template', $variables);
```

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/updating-plugins.html#rendering-templates

What I have and doesn't work:

```
return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('subscribing-module/src/views/default/index',['mypost' => $request]);
```

Returned error for above: Unable to find the template “subscribing-module/src/views/default/index”.

Here is the direct path from the root of the website:
modules/subscribingmodule/src/views/default/index.php

Bootstrap in config/app.php:

```
'bootstrap' => ['subscribing-module'],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path would be

```
return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('subscribing-module/templates/default',['mypost' => $request]);
```

And the file lives in `modules/subscribingmodule/src/templates/default/index.twig`